# Typescript can't import function that is exported from a module

Tags: typescript

This should be such a simple problem but for some reason I can't figure it out.

I have two files:

```
//Exporter.ts
export module Exporter {
     function foo = { return 1; }
}

//Importer.ts
import { foo } from './Exporter';
```

This gives me a typescript error `Exporter has no exported member foo`

But it's clearly being exported. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `export module...` wrapping code inside `Exporter.ts`.

The entirety of `Exporter.ts` became a module as soon as you added the `export` keyword to it.

Simply write:

```
// Exporter.ts
export function foo() { return 1; }


// Importer.ts
import { foo } from './Exporter';
```